Mysteriously high Memory usage on Linux
I'm getting steadily increasing memory usage over time. A logout then login does nothing to alleviate the issue, only a full reboot does which makes me suspect it is related to a root process.
I wonder if the GPUs have something to do with this as I have a dual AMD system (iGPU+dGPU). How can I troubleshoot this issue? This is happening even with no significant graphical load (just the desktop).
The system is a laptop running Debian 12 with KDE Plasma desktop. htop doesn't show any process with such high memory usage.
(And yes I'm talking about resident memory, not cached).

Is there an issue though? Do you see any problems? Linux is designed to use as much RAM as it can. See https://www.linuxatemyram.com/

Did you try sudo htop or ps_mem?

@terdon I know that Linux does use memory for caching. I'm talking about real used memory not accounting for the cache.

have you searched "KDE memory leak" ... lots to go through

htop doesn't show any user process with unusual memory usage. Anyways it appears that this memory is some sort of cache that is being misreported as used memory. I caused a deliberate memory leak and when the system recovered from it the extra GBs were freed. I also tried to drop the kernel caches and it did the same.

Are you using ZFS?

No I'm using BTRFS with compress-force=3 and zstd on a LUKS encrypted drive @muru

The memory usage turned out to be slabs @muru


only a full reboot does which makes me suspect it is related to a root process....

you did not specify a lot of other important information, for example if this is a server with gui Redhat Enterprise Linux type of install.. on a server which has multiple users, then a simple login/logoff of just you essentially means nothing...
assuming you mean a single user PC type of install of Linux, the fact (if you are correct in the first place) that you did identify increasing memory usage over time then my question is how did you identify that and under what operating conditions, and then were you not able to track it to a specific process?
https://superuser.com/questions/398862/linux-find-out-what-process-is-using-all-the-ram
https://learn.redhat.com/t5/General/how-to-find-process-memory-usage-from-RAM-in-linux/td-p/37223
